# Why would I be getting the error: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets on a simple once a day trigger?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I've searched around and still can't find anything directly related to the failure message I'm receiving. The script hasn't changed and it used to run just fine, but now in the past week or so it's failing more and more often. There are only 3 triggers on this file onOpen, onEdit(e) and the installed trigger that calls the percentChange function once a day in the morning.  It's super simple, it grabs 2 named ranges, one is a column of percentages and the other contains the length of that data and then copies the percentages to another column so that we can track the daily percentage difference.

Here is the code([link to a bare spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fUUBt6aYqWVU76WQHKqHH7TynxwzLPqy31ZL7Ke1oFA/edit?usp=sharing)):

```
function percentChange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Overview Status');

  var calcPercentRangeObject = ss.getRange('calcPerc');
  var calcPercentRow = calcPercentRangeObject.getRow()+2;
  var calcPercentColumn = calcPercentRangeObject.getColumn();

  var dataRangeObject = ss.getRange('numCabs');
  var dataRow = dataRangeObject.getRow()+2;
  var dataColumn = dataRangeObject.getColumn();
  var dataLength =  dataRangeObject.getValue();
  var currentPercent = ss.getRange(calcPercentRow, calcPercentColumn, dataLength, 1).getValues();

  ss.getRange(dataRow, dataColumn, dataLength, 1).setValues(currentPercent);

}
```

Should I add a delay?  That seems like a "janky" workaround...

[image: Latest failure]

[image: Previous failures and completions]

Another question: why does this code take 10+seconds to run from the trigger but generally takes less than a second to run from the script editor?

---

Edit: <s>It's not really a correct fix but I put in a 400ms delay after line 6 and have only gotten the error message once more...what an odd work around...</s>
This stopped working, I tried multiple delays spread out and removing the delay altogether.  I still don't understand why it's intermittent without the code changing?!?!

---

I am the owner.
It's shared with less than 60 people
I created the trigger manually
The only other installable trigger is onEdit()
The script is set to run when no-one would really be looking at it a couple hours before the shift would start.

Comment: How complex is your spreadsheet? (number of cells, sheets, use of volatile functions, use of array functions like MMULT, use of import functions like IMPORTRANGE..., custom functions) How long it usually takes the spreadsheet to be ready for editing when opening (recalculation time)?

Comment: There are some array formulas, import ranges, etc. I could make a copy and share it if that'd be helpful?  Even on my phone it doesn't usually take more than a few seconds to load/update.

Comment: Adding a time delay stopped working reliably, why is this issue so intermittent?  It almost makes me think this is a Google issue?

Comment: The second screenshoot shows several `percentChange Time-Driven triggered at the same time`. It's very likely that you script has several time-driven triggers, if so, delete all of them. In order to help you to find what caused the problem add more details about you are creating the time-driven trigger. If you think that this is a Google issue, raise an issue report through the [Google Apps Script issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B).

Comment: It's set to run once a day, and is the only time based trigger, at 5-6am. I'll submit to Google and see what comes up.  Thanks

Comment: @MicahKuiper How many `importrange` functions do you have linking to that sheet? From my experience, it seems that the more of those function used to link to the sheet, the higher the chances that I get that error. Gsheets might be counting those also as an invocation when it updates the links? I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the limit used to be 50 at one point but I'm a little over that.  This sheet shouldn't ever have to be more than 60-70...which is still probably pushing it.

Comment: I wonder if the importrange pulling data counts as an "invocation"

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas, quotas are per account and per day, so triggers created for other project scripts may be consuming your account quota.

| Feature | Consumer (e.g., gmail.com) and G Suite free edition (legacy) | Google Workspace accounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Triggers total runtime | 90 min / day | 6 hr / day |

Answer (score -1):

[image: 0]

**https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas**

> Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account. This indicates that the script began executing too many times in a short period. It most commonly occurs for custom functions that are called repeatedly in a single spreadsheet. To avoid this error, code your custom functions so that they only need to be called once per range of data, as explained in the guide to custom functions.

Comment: I don't think that tiny script is anywhere near those limits.

Answer (score -2):

I think this has to do with the amount of time onEdit is being invoked. Maybe try to limit the amount of times this function is invoked per second. For me, I needed to only send 30 rows to the sheet at a time, let it process, and then try again. Let us know if that helps or you disagree.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152839)